# Где найти память под видеоконтент?

Tags: сервер, память, хостинг

Есть сайт в базе данных которого содержится очень много ссылок (прямых) на видео, задача заключается в том, что все это видео нужно скачать, а как сделать если на сервере всего 1 ГБ памяти, а нужно как минимум 500ГБ (100тыс. видео). На хостинге можно заказать максимум 100ГБ и то за очень большую цену 4000 руб\мес, есть ли какие-нибудь дешевые варианты решения проблемы?

Comment: Дропбокс, яндекс-диск, облако mail.ru, ютьюб и т. д.?

Comment: И где мне взять около 500ГБ на этих облачных хранилищах?

Comment: Либо вспомнить, что на mail.ru когда-то терабайт раздавали, либо просто пачку аккаунтов завести, либо купить.

Comment: На яндекс-диске есть терабайт за 200 рублей в месяц, но так как это облако для юзеров, то оно может не подойти для некоторых технических задач (но если просто хранить для себя, то подойдёт)

Comment: Dropbox Pro: 8,25 $ на пользователя в месяц, 1 ТБ места - https://www.dropbox.com/business

Comment: @andreymal, у него вроде даже api есть?

Comment: @Qwertiy не знаю про api, но webdav есть

Comment: А терабайт за 200 рублей в месяц, его можно скажем в лиуксе подключить как дополнительную папку к серверу?

Comment: Через webdav как папку можно будет подключить (однако производительность напрямую зависит от скорости и задержке интернета и скорее всего такая папка будет тормозить)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовать для хранения файлов Яндекс-диск.

На данный момент [1 TB стоит 200 руб/мес или 2000 руб/год](https://disk.yandex.ru/pay/tariffs/).
Также [имеется api](https://tech.yandex.ru/disk/) для программного доступа, в том числе [REST](https://tech.yandex.ru/disk/rest/) и [WebDAV](https://tech.yandex.ru/disk/webdav/).

Comment: Отлично, мне это нравится, 200 рублей в месяц вообще копейки, только вот не будет тормозить если я буду дергать контент через АПИ?

Comment: @БазеликЗеленый, во-первых, это будет зависеть от скорости интернета на сервере. Однако, той же скоростью будет и для пользователя скачивание ограничиваться. Я очень сомневаюсь, что у твоего сервера (вероятно, тоже недорогого) скорость соединения будет выше чем у яндекса. Впрочем, можно же для начала на бесплатном тарифе попробовать и решить, подходит этот вариант или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Нужен VDS, для ваших нужд можно найти евро за 7 в месяц. С панелью вроде webmin.

Comment: На VDS евро за 7 полтерабайта, к сожалению, не влезут

Comment: https://contabo.com/?show=vps

Comment: А вот это прикольно, но, подозреваю, где-то подвох

Comment: Я пользуюсь ими, достаточно высокий аптайм и подвохов за года 4 не заметил.